# Is this an acceptable Ajax action for a CakePHP auto complete?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, autocomplete

I am relatively new to  CakePHP and was wondering how advanced users structure their ajax methods. The purpose of code this is to create a JSON list of matched products for a jQuery autocomplete.

```
 function autocomplete() {
            $terms = $this->params['url']['q'];
            if (!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $products = $this->Product->find('list', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Product.name LIKE' => '%'.$terms.'%',
                    ),
                    'limit' => 7,
                    'order' => 'Product.name',
                    'contain' => false
                ));
                exit(json_encode($products));
            } else {
                $this->redirect();
            }
        }
```

It feels a bit ballsy to just throw an exit() but then again, I don't need to run any views do I surely?

Comment: Yep that's okay, I do the same way.

Comment: no its not ok, as that is 'view' code in the 'controller', mvc 101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've done in the past:

In `config/routes.php`, add the following:

```
Router::mapResources(array('restaurants', 'items'));
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

In `app/app_controller.php`:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->isApiCall()) {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
    }
}

function isApiCall() {
    return $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()
        || $this->RequestHandler->isXml()
        || $this->RequestHandler->prefers('json');
}
```

Then in `app/views/items` and `app/views/restaurants`, I have a `json` folder under each with the corresponding view file to each action in the controller. Requests are made with the `.json` extension.

Lastly, I have a layout file in `app/views/layouts/json/default.ctp` with the following:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

---

For example, `http://mydomain.com/items/view.json` maps to `app/views/items/json/view.ctp` which contains:

```
<?php echo $javascript->object($item); ?>
```

`$item` was populated in the `app/controllers/items_controller.php` file.

Not sure if that helps for adds to the confusion, but that's how I've used JSON in my CakePHP apps.

**UPDATE:** Added layout information.

Comment: Thanks - I have an intimate knowledge of the CakePHP manual and API docs ;)

Comment: I have experimented with your implementation and I am getting an error that it is asking for a layout at: /app/views/layouts/json/default.ctp, Should I create blank file with just echo $content_for_layout in it, additionally, is it bad practice to create a completely separate action for my autocomplete?

Comment: I added the layout file info, you were correct on what to put in there. For the autocomplete, you could have a controller for all autocompletes or an autocomplete action in each controller...it's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I use an ajax layout with nothing in it except

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>
```

Then I just make an autocomplete.ctp view in which I echo the json encoded variable.

autocomplete.ctp

```
<?php echo json_encode($products); ?>
```