# How can I create a smart auto complete form field in CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp, autocomplete, helper

I want to create an auto complete field in my form..

the field will give suggestions every time the content of the field is changed..

when the user submits, if the typed data doesn't exist in the database, it should be created...

btw, i prefer to use jQuery for any javascript code...

any guidance for doing this will be appreciated...

thanx in advance

Comment: Read/Upvote my question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975196/is-this-an-acceptable-ajax-action-for-a-cakephp-auto-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best approach would be to check [the documentation for Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and see which way to access the autocomplete data is suitable for your situation.

Assuming you'll use a method with a remote datasource you create an action in your controller that returns the required data in JSON format and point your autocomplete script to this action.

As for saving any non-existing data automatically, that's something you can handle in another controller action (the one that gets fired when you submit the form) that checks if the submitted data exists and if not, creates a new entry.

Comment: thank you very much ..  
I already downloaded jQuery UI and trying to learn how to use it...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to integrate the `autocomplete` functionality into Cake's existing `JsHelper`, you can't do so out of the box. You have to extend the `JsHelper` and `JQueryEngine` classes to do it.

I've written some instructions here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/cake-php/aZo37UT1wp8/discussion

Otherwise, you can just include raw JavaScript/jQuery code in your view templates inside `<script>` tags.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanx @tokes ,  
for the moment, i'm just trying make it work  
in the soon future, i'll consider extending the helper classes cuz that will make it easier to add more auto-complete fields...